# Two cases while trying to print NULL, one works, other SegFaults

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

In the following:

```
printf("Example%s\n",NULL);
printf("%s\n",NULL);
```

I get the output as:

```
Example(null)
Segmentation Fault
```

When I tried backtrace in GDB it shows `printf()` is converted to `puts()`. But I can't seem to understand why this happens.

BTW I found [this](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=4128) article but still can't seem to make sense.

Comment: `gcc` does various such optimizations. See section 2.3 and 3.1 in particular of http://www.ciselant.de/projects/gcc_printf/gcc_printf.html

Comment: Also see this `gcc` bug report for more discussion on why this isn't considered a bug: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25609

Comment: A similar question: [Not getting segmentation fault in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861833/not-getting-segmentation-fault-in-c)

Comment: @shf301: I found this later version of the bug: http://sources.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10818

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The standard says that passing a `NULL` pointer as argument to a `printf` with `%s` specifier is undefined behavior<sup>1</sup> (i.e. anything can happen), so both behaviors are licit.

In the first case, the standard library (in particular, the `printf` code) is doing you a favor by printing `(null)`.

In the second case, instead, the optimizer understands that your `printf` can be replaced by a `puts` (which is more efficient) without any change to the "observable behavior" of the program, and so it replaces it. But, `puts` does not happen to contain the `NULL`-checking code of the `printf`, and thus you get a segmentation fault.

---

1. C99, §7.19.6.1, ¶8:

   > the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type.

   ¶9:

   > If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

   You fall in this last case, because `NULL` is not "a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type.

Comment: Exactly; the second `printf` just prints the given argument followed by a newline, which is exactly what `puts` does; the first one, instead, do somewhat more complicated stuff. Anyhow, these are implementation-specific details: the important thing is that you must not pass `NULL` as argument for a `printf` with `%s`, because it's undefined behavior.